# Identifier "unlock" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-c++, botan

In this example code

http://botan.randombit.net/manual/fpe.html

there is a method that I am trying to use in a Visual C++ managed wrapper, but I keep getting compile error on the 'unlock'  What is this? (could it be mutex::unlock)  And how can i resolve the error?

```
std::vector<byte> sha1(const std::string& acct_name)
   {
   SHA_160 hash;
   hash.update(acct_name);
   return unlock(hash.final());
   }
```

Error   16  error C3861: 'unlock': identifier not found

EDIT:  My Stdafx.h file now looks like this but it is still not compiling (even after including secmem.h)

```
#pragma once

#include <botan/botan.h>
#include <botan/fpe_fe1.h>
#include <botan/sha160.h>
#include <botan/secmem.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
```

EDIT:  Additional information - version of Botan library I'm using is Version 1.10.9 (latest Stable).  I compiled using the python script and did not exclude any modules (built it with everything) in debug mode.

Comment: Looks like [`unlock`](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/namespaceBotan.html#a07b99a8cd5ed8949c8645dc15c8b6659) converts from `secure_vector` to `std::vector`. The online documentation states the method is declared at `secman.h`.

Comment: @wendelbsilva still no luck after including the header you mentioned.

Comment: do you still get the same error after the include? If yes, would you mind adding the version of Botan library you are using.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed that the class `SHA_160` has another [`final`](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1Buffered__Computation.html#a71e7df2fab206504a5edb69d64d675f5) method where you can pass as a parameter a `vector<byte>` to get the output. With this method, you wouldnt need the `unlock` fuction.

Comment: Try to _rebuild_ your solution, sometimes changing a precompiled header and recompiling current source file doesn't pick up the changes

Comment: @wendelbsilva added more info in my OP - current stable release 1.10.9

Comment: @erotavlas I hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked and looks like Botan v. [1.10.9](http://fossies.org/dox/Botan-1.10.9/namespaceBotan.html) doesn’t have `unlock`. You have two options.

The version 1.10.9 has another [`final`](http://fossies.org/dox/Botan-1.10.9/classBotan_1_1Buffered__Computation.html) method where you can pass a vector of `byte` as reference to get the return.

Something like:

```
byte out[hash.output_length()];
hash.final(out);
```

Another option is to convert from `SecureVector` to `std::vector`.

```
SecureVector<byte> temp = hash.final();
std::vector<byte> ret(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

Depending of my application, I would chose one over the other.

.

Just in case someone come to this question and is using Botan 1.11.

The method [`unlock`](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/namespaceBotan.html#a07b99a8cd5ed8949c8645dc15c8b6659) to convert from `SecureVector` to `std::vector` is in the header `secman.h`.
In addition, the class SHA_160 has another [`final`](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1Buffered__Computation.html#a71e7df2fab206504a5edb69d64d675f5) method where you can pass as a parameter a `std::vector<byte>` to get the output. With this method, you wouldnt need the unlock function.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Any ideas why in their example (original ink above to FPE example)  they pass result of this sha1 method to SymmetricKey.  The result is of type std::vector<byte>  but I see no constructor for SymmetricKey that takes a parameter of that type.

Comment: The [`SymmetricKey`](http://fossies.org/dox/Botan-1.10.9/symkey_8h_source.html) constructor for 1.10.9 doesnt accept `std::vector`. Although, it accept a byte array (first option of the solution). Why they convert? I dont know but I would assume they wants to use `key` in a function that only accept `SymmetricKey` as parameter. That would be my guess.

Comment: Ok then since I want to pass the result to create a SymmetricKey then I shall use your first solution.  However Intellisense underlines the hash  on this line  byte out[hash.output_length()];  because it says expression must have a constant value.

Comment: In c++, the variable in the declaration of the array need to be constant at the compilation time. That means `byte out[size]` will not work (sry). You can allocate manually the size you want using `new` (but that's BAD). Or, if you are using c++ 11 you can create a vector `std::vector<byte> out(hash.output_length())` and use it in the final function like:  `hash.final(out.data);`.

Comment: This sha1 method is working now for me, but I have no clue how to pass the result to the SymmetricKey.  The example they posted does not work.   If you have any idea please let me know.  I posted last week to the mailing list for Botan but no reply yet.

Comment: One of the `SymmetricKey` constructor receives an array of bytes as parameter `(const byte in[], size_t len)`. If you have a array of byte, try to see if you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial uses this

```
using namespace Botan;
```

Maybe it is a namespace problem. Either you also declare the Botan namespace as "using", or you use `Botan::unlock` instead of unlock.

I'd recommend the second one, even if it seems longer. It's worth it!